# INNER JOIN if null columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

```
x table 
id - name   - balance
1 - test    - 500
2 - test 2  - 400
3 - test 3  - 300

y table
idx - idy - name
1   - null
2   - 5
3   - null
4   - 6

SELECT x.Name, SUM(x.Balance)
FROM x
INNER JOIN y ON ???

if IS NULL y.idy ON (x.id = y.idx)
ELSE ON (x.id = y.idy)
```

My English is not enough to tell the problem. but my problem is understandable

Comment: With that sample table data, what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try ANSI SQL standard `coalesce()` function to check `null` values

```
SELECT x.Name, SUM(x.Balance) [Balance] FROM x
join y ON coalesce(y.idy, y.idx) = x.id
group by x.Name
```

Result :

```
Name    Balance
test    500
test 3  300
```

Comment: Thank you. Solved literally

Answer (score 1):

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a90a5/2)

You can use [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) like below :

```
SELECT x.Name, SUM(x.Balance)
FROM x
INNER JOIN y ON x.id = isnull(y.idy, y.idx)
group by x.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Boolean logic looks like this:

```
ON (y.idy IS NULL AND x.id = y.idx) OR (x.id = y.idy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT     x.Name,
           SUM(x.Balance)
FROM       x
INNER JOIN y
  ON       (y.idy IS NULL AND x.id = y.idx) OR (x.id = y.idy)
GROUP BY   x.Name;
```